# Int conditional always returning true? Python

Tags: python, int, conditional-statements

I have a function called check defined like so

```
def check(n):
    if n > 17325551999:
        return True
    return False
```

which is always returning true. eg

```
>check(1000000000)
True
>check(5)
True
```

Can anyone give me some insight as to why this is happening? Is it because the number is larger than the largest possible int?

edit: I've added a picture of my python prompt.

[image]

Comment: No, that's not what I am getting. Are you certain you are not using **strings** instead?

Comment: unrelated: you could return the result directly: `return n > 17325551999`, no need for if/else here.

Comment: `'5'` is not the same thing as `5`.

Comment: I am not passing strings. I've even done the int(n) function in the conditional and I am still getting the same result

Comment: `check` takes `num` as a parameter, but you are comparing the value of a global `n`.

Comment: I can't believe I missed that thanks

Comment: Tips for the future: if you'd tried your screenshot code snippet in a fresh console, you would have gotten a `NameError`, because it wouldn't have known what `n` was.  If you're using Python 3 -- as we all should now ;^) -- then if you accidentally tried comparing a string and an int, you'd have gotten a `TypeError: unorderable types: int() < str()`.

Answer (score 5):

*Updated answer:*

From your screenshot it is clear you didn't post the same code here as what you are actually running:

```
def check(num):
    if n > 17325551999:
        return True
    return False
```

either raises a `NameError` for `'n'` *or* tests `n` as a global if it *is* defined. The actual parameter to the function is called `num`, and is completely ignored in the function.

In other words, you'd have to assign to the `n` global to make your version work.

The fix is to test the right parameter:

```
def check(num):
    return num > 17325551999
```

*Previous answer before the screenshot was posted*:

You are not passing in integers. With integers your code works just fine:

```
>>> def check(n):
...     if n > 17325551999:
...         return True
...     return False
... 
>>> check(5)
False
```

Instead you are *probably* passing in strings instead:

```
>>> check('5')
True
```

In Python 2, numbers always sort before strings (a mistake remedied in Python 3), so **any** number is always going to be 'smaller' than a string:

```
>>> '0' > 0
True
```

Avoid this problem by making sure your function is called with an integer argument, or explicitly convert `n` in the function:

```
def check(n):
    return int(n) > 17325551999:
```

Note that the `>` operator already returns `True` or `False`, no need to use `if` here.

Comment: @BrianDillmann: From your screenshot it is clear you made a different mistake, yes. You did not post the same code here as what you are running.

Comment: yeah i was cooked a little too long